# How can I copy-paste multiple tabs of one Excel workbook into an existing Excel workbook into different sheets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

In AllCrypto.xlsx, I have data for Bitcoin, Litecoin, Ethereum, Ethereum Classic.....so on. I want to copy the data from those individual tabs of AllCrypto.xlsx to an already existing excel which is Formula.xlsx.
Instead of writing the below code redundantly for each cryptocurrency, I want to loop & map the sheetnames between the source to target excel and copy paste the data. How can I achieve this without wrting the lines of code seperately for each cyptocurrency.

```
wbs1 = '/Users/Desktop/Cypto/AllCrypto.xlsx'
wbs2 = '/Users/Desktop/Crypto/Formula.xlsx'

wb = load_workbook(wbs1)
wb2 = load_workbook(wbs2)

# Bitcoin
srcSheet1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('bitcoin1D')
tgtSheet1 = wb2.get_sheet_by_name('Bitcoin')

for i in range(1, srcSheet1.max_row+1):
    for j in range(1, srcSheet1.max_column+1):
        tgtSheet1.cell(row=i, column=j).value = srcSheet1.cell(row=i, column=j).value

wb.save(wbs1)
wb2.save(wbs2)

# Bitcoin Cash
srcSheet1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('bCash1D')
tgtSheet1 = wb2.get_sheet_by_name('Bitcoin Cash')

for i in range(1, srcSheet1.max_row+1):
    for j in range(1, srcSheet1.max_column+1):
        tgtSheet1.cell(row=i, column=j).value = srcSheet1.cell(row=i, column=j).value

wb.save(wbs1)
wb2.save(wbs2)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Appreciate it